# I need filter the list json generate with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put a class that is equal to the value of the option and I wanted it to pull only the "li" which has the same class and hide the others

Here is my attempt

```js
$('#select-editorial').change(function() {
  var valueedt = this.value;
  console.log(valueedt);

  if ($('.list-notice').find(valueedt)) {
    $('.list-notice li').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-notices">
  <li class="País">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="img/noticias/7.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80" height="163" width="277">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80</h1>
        <p>"Ea excepteur deserunt occaecat et consequat eu do ut ut labore et laborum. Occaecat ipsum labore et mollit exercitation consequat commodo dolore. Cupidatat culpa velit quis occaecat non ipsum duis. "
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="Rio">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="img/noticias/3.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games" height="163" width="277">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games</h1>
        <p>"Non amet tempor magna minim. Veniam quis ad labore et quis anim ad. Incididunt do ullamco eiusmod sit officia irure dolore et pariatur dolor. Quis nulla ex fugiat esse ut magna. Non ut fugiat id anim do officia eu quis do qui amet minim magna.
          "
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

And Follow the select form:

<select class="select" name="select-editorial" id="select-editorial">
  <option>Editoria</option>
  <option value="Esporte">Esporte</option>
  <option value="País">País</option>
  <option value="Rio">Rio</option>
  <option value="Cultura">Cultura</option>
  <option value="Internacional">Internacional</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First it's `.list-notices` not `.list-notice`. Second, when you are trying to find the element with `valueedt`, since it's a class selector you need to prefix it with `.`

Comment: And there isn't any JSON here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a common class to all you li elements. Then, you can hide them easily and activate only one of them:

```
<ul class="list-notices">
<li class="País myClass"><a href="#"><div class="image"><img src="img/noticias/7.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80" height="163" width="277"></div><div class="text"><h1>Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80</h1><p>"Ea excepteur deserunt occaecat et consequat eu do ut ut labore et laborum. Occaecat ipsum labore et mollit exercitation consequat commodo dolore. Cupidatat culpa velit quis occaecat non ipsum duis.
"</p></div><div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span></div></a></li>

<li class="Rio myClass"><a href="#"><div class="image"><img src="img/noticias/3.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games" height="163" width="277"></div><div class="text"><h1>Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games</h1><p>"Non amet tempor magna minim. Veniam quis ad labore et quis anim ad. Incididunt do ullamco eiusmod sit officia irure dolore et pariatur dolor. Quis nulla ex fugiat esse ut magna. Non ut fugiat id anim do officia eu quis do qui amet minim magna.
"</p></div><div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, the jQuery:

```
$('#select-editorial').change(function(){
    var valueedt = $(this).value;
    console.log(valueedt);

    $('.myClass').hide();
    $('.' + valueedt).show().addClass('active');

});
```

And, if you can't add common class (myClass):

```
$('#select-editorial').change(function(){
    var valueedt = $(this).value;
    console.log(valueedt);

    $('.list-notices li').hide();
    $('.list-notices li.' + valueedt).show().addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i get the li with the class of value selected and show, if not have the class, hide the element

```js
$('#select-editorial').change(function(){
  var valueedt = '.' + this.value;
  $('.list-notices li' +valueedt).addClass('active').show();
  $('.list-notices li').not(valueedt).removeClass('active').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-notices">
<li class="País"><a href="#"><div class="image"><img src="img/noticias/7.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80" height="163" width="277"></div><div class="text"><h1>Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80</h1><p>"Ea excepteur deserunt occaecat et consequat eu do ut ut labore et laborum. Occaecat ipsum labore et mollit exercitation consequat commodo dolore. Cupidatat culpa velit quis occaecat non ipsum duis.
"</p></div><div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span></div></a></li>

<li class="Rio"><a href="#"><div class="image"><img src="img/noticias/3.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games" height="163" width="277"></div><div class="text"><h1>Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games</h1><p>"Non amet tempor magna minim. Veniam quis ad labore et quis anim ad. Incididunt do ullamco eiusmod sit officia irure dolore et pariatur dolor. Quis nulla ex fugiat esse ut magna. Non ut fugiat id anim do officia eu quis do qui amet minim magna.
"</p></div><div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span></div></a></li>
</ul>

<select class="select" name="select-editorial" id="select-editorial">
                        <option>Editoria</option>
                        <option value="Esporte">Esporte</option>
                        <option value="País">País</option>
                        <option value="Rio">Rio</option>
                        <option value="Cultura">Cultura</option>
                        <option value="Internacional">Internacional</option>
                      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spell the class correctly and use hide and show

Also you need to prefix the class name with a "."

Like this:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tzg5gzLw/)

```js
$('#select-editorial').on("change",function() {
  var valueedt = this.value;
  console.log(valueedt);
  $('.list-notices li').hide();

  $('.list-notices .'+valueedt).show();
});
```

```css
li { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-notices">
  <li class="País">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="img/noticias/7.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80" height="163" width="277">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Como Facebook, Google e Twitter seriam na década de 80</h1>
        <p>"Ea excepteur deserunt occaecat et consequat eu do ut ut labore et laborum. Occaecat ipsum labore et mollit exercitation consequat commodo dolore. Cupidatat culpa velit quis occaecat non ipsum duis. "
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="Rio">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="img/noticias/3.jpg" class="img-resp" alt="Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games" height="163" width="277">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Grupo de artistas usa Cubos Mágicos para recriar personagens de games</h1>
        <p>"Non amet tempor magna minim. Veniam quis ad labore et quis anim ad. Incididunt do ullamco eiusmod sit officia irure dolore et pariatur dolor. Quis nulla ex fugiat esse ut magna. Non ut fugiat id anim do officia eu quis do qui amet minim magna.
          "
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn"><span class="arrow"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



<select class="select" name="select-editorial" id="select-editorial">
  <option>Editoria</option>
  <option value="Esporte">Esporte</option>
  <option value="País">País</option>
  <option value="Rio">Rio</option>
  <option value="Cultura">Cultura</option>
  <option value="Internacional">Internacional</option>
</select>
```